# Can we install Express edition and Standard edition of SQL Server on same PC User?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using both SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2, I have a situation where I need both on the same computer and in same user.

But with the different versions.

I wanted to installed SQL Server 2008 Express and SQL Servre 2008 R2 Standard Edition.

My question is can we do this? if yes then can you please guide me how to install it.

Comment: i had installed both instances but when i open 1 instance it will not allow me to open the second one. i mean when i open the SQL SERVER 2008 Express Edition Instance it will not allow me to open instance of SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Standard Edition. actually i have two different instances installed, for SQL SERVER 2008 EE instance name is SQLEXPRESSEE for SQL SERVER 2008 R2 SE instance name is SQLEXPRESSSE when i connect SQLEXPRESSEE it wont allow me to open SQLEXPRESSSE and when i connect to SQLEXPRESSSE it wont allow me to open SQLEXPRESSEE can you please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes of course you can do this. Also, there's nothing special to "guide you" for installation - just install them.

The only point you need to be aware of: if you have multiple versions of SQL Server installed, they have to have a separate **instance name** (which you pick at install time).

By default, a "regular" SQL Server installs as a "default instance" without explicit instance name. SQL Server Express by default uses the `SQLEXPRESS` instance name.

So basically: yes it's totally possible, just pick separate instance names for both installations!

Comment: Hey i had installed both instances but when i open 1 instance it will not allow me to open the second one. i mean when i open the SQL SERVER 2008 Express Edition Instance it will not allow me to open instance of SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Standard Edition. actually i have two different instances installed,
for SQL SERVER 2008 EE instance name is SQLEXPRESSEE
for SQL SERVER 2008 R2 SE instance name is SQLEXPRESSSE
when i connect SQLEXPRESSEE it wont allow me to open SQLEXPRESSSE and when i connect to SQLEXPRESSSE it wont allow me to open SQLEXPRESSEE can you please help me.

Comment: @VikrantMore: what is ***it*** that doesn't allow you to connect to the other instance? SQL Server Mgmt Studio? Or what else??

Comment: yes it is not.yes, i think it is not allowing me to connect agent at a same time. sorry it is regarding to the agent, it is now allowing me to connect 2 agent at the same time. can  you please help me.

Comment: ok should we continue here or i ask as a different question can you please help me in it.

Comment: @VikrantMore: this question was about **installing** two instances of SQL Server - I answered that. The problem with two separate agents is a **separate** question - so ask another question and explain your issues - someone will certainly help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12980/discussion-between-vikrant-more-and-marc-s)