# how to automatically create aspnetdb.mdf to store administration security data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i was trying the MVC Music Store project but i encountered a problem when going to the administration tool, it says

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid    server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.
>
> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

I searched online and tried numerous ways and found out it is because i don't have sqlserver express edition, so i can't use the AttachDbfile feature to auto create aspnetdb.msd file to store administration data

as i stated in the title, the truth is i installed sql server 2012 express first, but because i need reporting services i then installed the full sqlserver 2012, but i didn't create a new instance when installing instead i selected adding new feature to existing instance, so why does the VS say i don't have the express version now, i am totally buffled

does this mean if i want to use the app_data file feature again, i have to install sql server 2012 express as a new instance again?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Express Edition is the only edition of SQL Server that supports User Instances. Thus, if you want to use a User Instance and do not have SQL Server Express Edition installed, you must install SQL Server Express Edition.

If you have a "full" version of SQL Server, I would suggest using the ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool (aspnet_regsql.exe) to create the equivalent of the aspnetdb.mdf database.

Edit:
As indicated in the answer to [Can we install Express edition and Standard edition of SQL Server on same PC User?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11183673/1414000), it is possible to install both SQL Server Express Edition and a "full" version of SQL Server on the same computer.

However, it sounds like you performed an [Edition Upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707783.aspx) which replaced SQL Server Express Edition with the "full" version of SQL Server.  If this is the case and you still want to use a User Instance, install SQL Server Express Edition again.

If you are not sure which edition(s) of SQL Server is installed, see [How to determine the version and edition of SQL Server and its component](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185).

Comment: thx i know all this, i am just wondering why after i added new features to the existing Express instance using the standard edition, i lost the functions of the express like supporting user instance

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your comment.  Please either accept my answer, or let me know what information I am missing.