# Upgrading from SQL Server 2012 Express to Standard

Tags: sql-server

I have a phone server running Window Server 2008. The server software is currently using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express Edition. I created an IVR application that has created a second database using the same SQL Server instance.

I found out post-development that the version of SQL Server installed on the server was Express and NOT Standard like I had thought. I checked the SQL Server Configuration manager and noticed that the instance is `MSSQLSERVER`, but it is running express. The phone system software I am using is proprietary and I cannot get in to change/modify connection strings.

My question is:

Is it reasonable to assume that upgrading from SQL Server 2012 Express to SQL Server 2012 Standard is safe? Does upgrading change the connection string, or instance name? Or is there anything I should be aware of during the upgrade? Or would it be better to just run Standard alongside Express?

Thanks!

I have read various articles saying that the connection string doesn't change, but I would like some input from someone who has actually upgraded from Express to Standard.

Comment: you **NEED** to change version? notice that i didn't write 'upgrade' but 'change'. btw you can run both [sql server standard and express on the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183673/can-we-install-express-edition-and-standard-edition-of-sql-server-on-same-pc-use).

Comment: I would like to use the import/export wizard and save the package files. My understanding is that the package file can be used to automate data importing. Altough I can use the import/export wizard in express it doesn't let me save the package file. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: this is stated in the [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186943%28v=sql.110%29.aspx): In SQL Server Express, the option to save the package created by the wizard is not available. if you use that feature you have to install the standard edition.